# Any way to add lines to build.prop upon clicking button?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, line

Is there any function/method that I can use that'll add lines to the devices build.prop?

For example there is a build.prop line - `pm.sleep_mode=1`

And I want that line to be added to my device's build.prop when I click a button.
How can I achieve this? Have searched but it only come sup with scripts?:S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st, you need a rooted android device.
2nd, use Runtime.getRuntime().exec() to invoke the script as root user. the script may like:

```
mount -o remount,rw ... #depends on your system partition block device
cat "pm.sleep_mode=1" >> /system/build.prop
setprop pm.sleep_mode 1
```